# Need to display alert if no checkboxes are selected in JavaScript, my current method isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm getting an error for "Object Expected" - the error points to the first If... from everything I read about checkboxes (checkboxes never work for me) and what I read about multiple conditionals, this is right? Even though it isn't...

```
var lucy = window.document.alice

if (lucy.ch1.checked != "true" && lucy.ch2.checked != "true" && lucy.ch3.checked != "true" && lucy.ch4.checked != "true")
{
    alert('Atleast one box must be checked');
}

if (lucy.skeletor.value = "no")
{
    alert('Default Option is not a valid selection.');
}
```

Comment: @Abat: WHY??? - jQuery is not the answer to everything in the world.

Comment: @mplungjan: Don't panic, anyway. jQuery makes working with JavaScript much easier. Also I didn't say "use jQuery, otherwise you can't achieve what you want", I just asked, can OP use jQuery

Comment: @Abat: Not panicking. Just amazing how often the jq word is mentioned here. Regardsless of complexity. If Mike needs to know how to write javascript, then throwing jQuery at him for a validation of 4 checkboxes is overkill imnho :)

Comment: JQuery is *not* always the right solution: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72928/what-does-douglas-crockford-mean-when-he-says-jquery-doesnt-scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `lucy.ch1.checked != "true"` part. Just say if (`!lucy.ch1.checked && !lucy.ch2.checked && ...`). Furthermore use `if`, not `If`, javascript is case sensitive. Your code is a guarantee for failure, so maybe you want it to rewrite it to something like:

```
var lucy = document.alice; //a form of some kind?
if (!lucy.ch1.checked && !lucy.ch2.checked 
    && !lucy.ch3.checked && !lucy.ch4.checked)
{
  alert('At least one box must be checked');
}

if (lucy.skeletor.value === "no")
{
  alert('Default Option is not a valid selection.');
}
```

Comment: Good Lord, you guys are always so full of win. Thank you this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!(lucy.ch1.checked || lucy.ch2.checked || lucy.ch3.checked))
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive - you need to use if()

Update: here is a how I would validate a form (I would not likely call the obejct lucy, but here you go):

```
function validate(lucy) {
  if (!lucy.ch1.checked && !lucy.ch2.checked && !lucy.ch3.checked && !lucy.ch4.checked) {
    alert('At least one box must be checked');
    return false;
  }
  if (lucy.skeletor.value = "no") {
    alert('Default Option is not a valid selection.');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have "" around true. In this case true is not a string, it's a boolean value, and you can just write true in stead.
You can make it even more simple by useing KooiInc's answer.